# How do I loop through input line by line and also go through each of those lines in C++;

Tags: c++, loops, input

So I'm trying to go through input line by line. Each line in the input is formatted like this:

> Words_More words_even more words_What I Need to Go Through_ Random_ Random_Etc.

With a random amount of word clusters (The words separated by '_')

I want, for each line, to be able to ignore all the words until I get to the fourth word cluster which in the example I gave would be: "What I Need To Go Through" and then store those separate words in some data structure that I haven't decided upon yet.

My first thought would be to use

```
    getline(cin, trash, '_');
```

three times and deal with the data that follows, but then how would I loop line by line until the end of the input?

Comment: Why is it in that format?

Comment: That's just how it's formatted, nothing I can do about it

Comment: How big is data? Can you double pass?

Comment: Data is about 100k lines+, can't double pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two options:

## use getline for each line, then parse it

use `getline(stream, string)` to get a line from your stream, and  store it into a string. Then construct an `istringstream` to parse this again (with the `getline` you thought of.

## get what you need, and then `ignore()` stuff unill the next newline

You do `getline()` thing, and then you call `ignore()` [(doc)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)
to read and discard the rest of the line, so you can start again with the next line.

which one you use is up to you. but the second one has slightly better performance, if you care about that stuff.